# Get row index of table row

Tags: angular, primeng

I have the following code:

```
> <p-column> <template let-col let-object="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate type="body">
<input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, i)"> </template></p-column>
```

I am using PrimeNG table with value of array and costume columns as shown above. I want to get either object or i variables in my onFileInputChange function, which hold rowData and rowIndex values and pass it to .ts file of component. However, I always get the value of first row and index value to be 0. In the HTML, when I display those values, everything is correct. What is wrong with this code, I am using things from PrimeNG docs?